# Only mark and count circles within given x-position

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have a working HoughCircles-Transformation, which finds circles in my video. The "i" in the for-loop beneath it gives the [x-position, y-position, radius] of each circle. I only want to draw on and count circles with the x-position 100 and 101.

```
# draw circle on blur window
        for i in all_circles_blured[0, :]:
            #print(i)
            #print(i[0])
            if i[0] == range(100, 102): #i[0] is the x-position
                cv2.circle(blur, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 5)  # draw the outer circle
                cv2.circle(blur, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 155, 0), 2)  # draw the center of the circle
                cv2.putText(blur, str(TabNumber), (i[0]-10, i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1)
                TabNumber += 1
```

The Error says: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

But as far as I know, both functions aren't suited for my problem.

Comment: You need to use `if i[0] in range(100, 102):`

Comment: Cool it worked, gonna mark the answer when the 2 days have passed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You need to use if i[0] in range(100, 102): – ZdaR"